# Why my local database(sql server) doesn't seed any data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am using MVC dotnet framework. I have got customer model
 which is below:

```
Model Before

     using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;

        namespace WebApplication5.Models
        {
            public class CustomerContext : DbContext
            {
                public CustomerContext() : base("CustomerDB")
                {
                    Database.SetInitializer(new        DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerContext>());
                }

                public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
            }
            public class Customer
            {
                public int id { get; set;}
                [Required]
                [StringLength(255)]
                public String Name { get; set;}
                public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set;}
                public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set;}
                public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
            }
        }
Model After 
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using WebApplication5.Configurations;

    namespace WebApplication5.Models
    {
        public class CustomerContext : DbContext
        {
            public CustomerContext() : base("CustomerContext")
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<CustomerContext>(new CustomerDBInitializer());
            }

                  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        }


        public class Customer
        {
            public int id { get; set;}
            [Required]
            [StringLength(255)]
            public String Name { get; set;}
            public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set;}
        }
    }
```

Below is my code sowing CustoemrRepository, which has all functions to delete, update, edit and add customers in customers table:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using WebApplication5.Models;


        namespace WebApplication5.Repositories.CustomersRepositories
        {
            public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository, IDisposable
            {
                private CustomerContext context;

                public CustomerRepository(CustomerContext context)
                {
                    this.context = context;
                }
                public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
                {
                    return context.Customers.ToList();
                }
                public Customer GetCustomerByID(int Id)
                {
                    return context.Customers.Find(Id);
                }
                public void InsertCustomer(Customer customer)
                {
                    context.Customers.Add(customer);
                }
                public void DeleteCustomer(int Id)
                {
                    Customer customer = context.Customers.Find(Id);
                    context.Customers.Remove(customer);
                }
                public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
                {
                    context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                public void Save()
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                private bool disposed = false;
                protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
                {
                    if (!this.disposed)
                    {
                        if (disposing)
                        {
                            context.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    this.disposed = true;
                }

                public void Dispose()
                {
                    Dispose(true);
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is my customerController:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Routing;
        using System.Web.Mvc;
        using WebApplication5.Models;
        using WebApplication5.Repositories.CustomersRepositories;

        namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
        {
            //[RoutePrefix("api/customers")]
            public class CustomersController : Controller
            {
                private ICustomerRepository iCustomerRepository;

                public CustomersController()
                {
                    this.iCustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository(new CustomerContext());
                }


                public CustomersController(CustomerRepository customerRepository)
                {
                    this.iCustomerRepository = customerRepository;
                }

                [Route("customers")]
                [HttpGet]
                // GET: Customers
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    var customers = iCustomerRepository.GetCustomers();
                    //return View(customers);
                    return Content("Hey");
                }
            }
        }
```

after that I ran migrations which made a local database (Sql Server) and customers Table.
Then I added another file which seeds data to databse:
and I ran migrations update command in package manager, but my customers table still shows no data and it is empty. Please Help
  updated Seed Data file

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using WebApplication5.Models;
        using WebApplication5.Repositories.CustomersRepositories;

        namespace WebApplication5
        {
                 public class CustomerDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CustomerContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(CustomerContext context)
    {
        IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer { id = 1, Name = "Jojo", IsSubscribedToNewsletter = true }
        };
        var customer1 = new Customer { id = 1, Name = "Jojo", IsSubscribedToNewsletter = true };
        context.Customers.AddRange(customers);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}            }

    [my customer table is still empty][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJoLm.png
```

Comment: Where and how do you call SeedData() ?

Comment: Check the connection string and make sure it is using the same file you added data to.  You can do a search and check on your computer for MDF files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--------------------------------------------------Using .NET EF6---------------------------------------------------------

```
   public CustomerContext() : base("CustomerContext")
{

}
```

In the "Configuration.cs" generated when you run the "Enable-Migrations", the seed method is where you will add the code to populate your database.

---

```
   protected override void Seed(WebApplication1.CustomerContext context)
    {

        IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer { id = 1, Name = "Jojo", IsSubscribedToNewsletter = true },
               new Customer { id = 2, Name = "Jojo", IsSubscribedToNewsletter = true }
        };

        context.Customers.AddRange(customers);

        base.Seed(context);

    }
```

--------------------------------------------------Using .NET EF CORE---------------------------------------------------------
I think that your CustomerContext is wrong, try with this. To add data while performing the migration, add this data to OnModelCreating method.

```
    public CustomerContext() : base()
    {
    }
    public CustomerContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
        string connectionString = "Server=localhost; Initial Catalog=TestCustomers;persist security info=True; Integrated Security = SSPI;";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasData(
            new Customer { id = 1, Name = "Jojo", IsSubscribedToNewsletter = true} 
        );

    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but as I tried that it threw so many errors
'CustomerContext' does not contain a definition for 'MembershipTypes' and no accessible extension method 'MembershipTypes' accepting a first argument of type 'CustomerContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'CustomerContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)': no suitable method found to override
'CustomerContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: and this The type or namespace name 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly The type or namespace name 'ModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: the first one is because to test your code i removed the 'MembershipTypes' class from the customer class, and because of that the customer that i'm adding in the model creation doesn't have that property. The other errors is because im using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, that's great. I am using MVC ASP.NET framework. Do I still need EntityFrameworkCore? is there a way to seed database without using EnitityFrameworkCore?

Comment: Thanks Pedro, Your code makes perfect sense and it should work, but my database is still empty, maybe there is something else wrong :-/

Comment: how do I add code here. The comment box is too small and plus it cramps whole code together , thanks

Comment: I have added the code above to post ModelBefore and ModelAfter and edited SeedData file at the bottom

Comment: your connection string Name before was "CustomerDB" and after is "CustomerContext" verify if you changed the name in the config file, if is still CustomerDB replace it. Then delete the database and run the migration again

Comment: I found the problem Kira, so when you run the command "Enable-Migrations" is created a "Configuration.cs" in this file there is a method called "Seed" is here that you should paste the code from the seed method above. I will update the solution above.

Comment: OMG!!!!!! you are a genius!!! I am soooooo thanksful to you. You dont how much it made me happy. I have been stuck in this problem for a week. You are amazing, thanks :) now I can sleep well tonight hahhh

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow account, lemme know if I somehow I can give you good review, thanks :)

Comment: No problem, click in the "up arrow", on left side of my answer, to mark it as useful changing the value from 0 to 1. thanks :)

Comment: I did it hahha but it says it is recorded but will update after you get 15 points then it will appear :) but I ticked your answer as useful as well, which does appear :)